# Give me a hint to solve this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2} dx$$

I don't have any clue as to where to even start. I am struggling on this one.

Please shed some light by giving me a **Hint**

Comment: Hint: Go read the part of your book that talks about partial fractions. It will explain exactly how to evaluate that integral.

Comment: In some sense, **partial fractions** is the answer when "I don't have any clue".  Certainly that is the starting point for many problems like this one.  BUT... in this case, when you carry out the partial fraction expansion, the result has one term... the original problem!  So now we need the SECOND step.

Comment: Isn't anything of the form 1/(ax+b)^p and 1/(ax^2+c^2)^p already past partial fractions?

Answer (score 13):

HINT:

Use [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)

$$x^2+x+1=\dfrac{(2x+1)^2+(\sqrt3)^2}4$$

Set $2x+1=\sqrt3\tan\theta$

Comment: lab bhattacharjee Thanxs!

Comment: can you explain how this hint works? I'd like to know where this technique would be useful

Comment: @Ooker, Please let me know if you face any problem in making the substitution

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** Since $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{n\geq 1}n z^{n-1}$,

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x^3)^2}\,dx &=& \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}n(1-x)^2 x^{3n-3}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}n\left(x^{3n-3}-2x^{3n-2}+x^{3n-1}\right)\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}n\left(\frac{1}{3n-2}-\frac{2}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n}\right)=\frac{2}{3} \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
In order to compute the last series, you may exploit the following identities involving the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b},\qquad \psi(1-z)-\psi(z)=\pi\cot(\pi z).$$
Obviously, this is not the only approach. You may also notice that the last series is related with a Dirichlet $L$-function evaluated at $s=1$; such a series is $L_{\chi}(1)$ where $\chi$ is the Legendre symbol $\pmod{3}$, and we may also exploit the [class number formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) $(2)+(5)$ in the link.

Comment: (+1) Like how you use an atomic bomb to crack this small nut here :)

Answer (score 6):

$$\dfrac{d\left[\dfrac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^2+x+1}\right]}{dx}$$

$$=\dfrac{(x^2+x+1)(2ax+b)-(ax^2+bx+c)(2x+1)}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

We need $1=(x^2+x+1)(2ax+b)-(ax^2+bx+c)(2x+1)=(a-b)x^2+(a-2c)x+b-c$

$\implies a-b=0,a-2c=0,b-c=1\implies \cdots$

Comment: That is a great but unmotivated answer. Could you explain how you expected the indefinite integral to be in the form $\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^2+x+1}$?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I didn't expect. But the derivative of $\dfrac1{x^2+x+1}$ must contain something of the form $$\dfrac{bx+c}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$   It also, reminded me of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Rational_functions